# cors not resolving inspite of setting headers, i dont want to use jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to invoke an api using ajax jquery , it should give me json response i used the below methos

```
 $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'http://example.com',
        headers:{

            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'X-Requested-With',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET',
        },

        //headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"},
        dataType: "json",



        success: function(msg) {
        alert("data loaded");
        console.log(msg);
        }
});
```

but this still gives me the below warning on console
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com

and it gives me error as
NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is response header it should be set from api which is `http://example.com` not from your own ajax request.

Comment: okay thanks for the clarification,i cannot touch the server side, so please tell me is there a method by which i can avoid cors from client side ajax request?

Comment: No you cannot avoid cors problem from client side ajax request...you have to ask the people whom web api you are consuming in your web app and tell them to add header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` when request will come from your domain..

Answer (score 3):

`Access-Control-Allow-*` are **response** headers, not request headers. They have to be set by `example.com`, not your JavaScript.

It would be a pretty pointless authorisation system if you could authorise your own code to read anyone else's website.

Answer (score 0):

The access-control-allow headers need to come from the webserver, not send by the client.
You can't set them in your call, you have to modify the webserver configuration.
A 401 indicates you need authentication, in that case the origin needs to be different to *. Alsow you need jQuery to allow to send authentication and on the server additional the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true header.
Also you need on the client side to enable cors with 
    $.support.cors = true;